# OAuth 2.0 Client IDs of Google for mobile app

Tags: android, react-native, google-api, google-oauth, google-client

I'm creating a mobile-app in react native, and I want to use there in Google photos, I want that every user will be possible to watch his photos and create/shared album.

I want also that my server side uploads photos to the albums of the users that shared album with my mobile app even the user is inactive in the mobile app.

I think this is the flow that I need (what to do for it ,OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for android/ios app or web app or both for example), my main problem is that I don't know what is exactly the redirect `URI`, and how it connects between my server side and the front/mobile-app:

The flow is:
(I'm using react native in the front)

Authorization Request on the Mobile app, and set `redirect_uri` in a way that redirects back to your app, i.e: claim that `URL` with your app. When you get the `auth` code in your app, send that `auth` code to your backend, and do the token request from your backend. That way, you'll have all tokens on the backend.

1.Authorization Request from mobile app to OAuth provider (e.g: Google).
2.Google responds with auth_code to your mobile app.
3.Send that auth_code to backend (this is your own Token Request route).
4.Do the Token Request on backend with the auth_code and get access_token and refresh_token -- here you have the possibility to store it.
5.Respond to the mobile app with the desired token so it can use it for authentication/authorization.

I have tried to do a android app for the front and web app for the server side but didnt succeed.

I read something about custom `URI` scheme. But didn't get it.